# Margin top on div inside another wrapper div

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm just new to front end coding, I am facing some problems about the `margin` here.
I have a `#header` div as a base, and other `div` inside it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

#headWrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  height: 85px;
  margin: auto;
  float: left;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url("img/logo.png");
  float: left;
  width: 350px;
  height: 78px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

#naviWrapper {
  float: left;
  max-width: 530px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 275px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.homeBTN,
.aboutBTN,
.productBTN,
.solutionBTN,
.contactBTN {
  float: left;
  margin: 5 20;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <div id="headWrapper">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <div id="naviWrapper">
        <div class="homeBTN">Home</div>
        <div class="aboutBTN">About us</div>
        <div class="productBTN">Products</div>
        <div class="solutionBTN">Solutions</div>
        <div class="contactBTN">Contact us</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

My problem is the inside `div` if I add `margin-top` on it, the whole `div` will goes down together, how can I just move the `div` inside the `#header`? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Try using padding instead of margin in your header div

Comment: Explanation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

**Summary of the changes**:

1. Remove all margins, floats and heights.
2. For the navigation links use the `<a href=""></a>` instead of `divs` and consider having `ul li a` structure.
3. Then to position the navigation vertically in the middle:

   - Add to `#header` container a `display: table;`
   - Add to `#headWrapper` a `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;`
4. To align the navigation's text in the middle use `text-align: center;`

**Code:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#header {
  display: table;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 135px;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  width: 100%;
}
#headWrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
#naviWrapper a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
#naviWrapper ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.logo {
  background-image: url("img/logo.png");
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="headWrapper">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <nav id="naviWrapper">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Solutions</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: SEO-wise `<nav>` would better dance instead of `<div id="naviWrapper">`. Also an inner `UL LI A` structure would be even better.

Comment: Hi guys, THanks alot.. im fixed my problem...thanks for prompt response, u guys r gorgeous!